# Regulator of abelian extensions of Q

Tags: arithmetic-geometry, algebraic-number-theory, l-functions, cyclotomic-fields

Let $K = \mathbb Q(\mu_m)$ and $\zeta_K$ it's Dedekind zeta function. We know from the class number formula that, around $0$:
$$\zeta_K(s) \sim s^{r_1+r_2-1}h(K)R(K)/w(K) $$
where $h,R,w$ stand for the size of the class group, the regulator and the size of the subgroup of roots of unity.

On the other hand, we have the decomposition:
$$\zeta_K(s) = \prod_\chi L(s,\chi)$$
where the product is over suitable Dirichlet characters and moreover, $L(0,\chi) = -B_{1,\chi}$ - the generalized Bernoulli numbers.

On the other hand, $R(K)$ should not be algebraic and there should be a corresponding transcendental contribution from $L(0,\chi)$ and the explicit formula for $B_{1\chi}$ shows that this comes only from those $\chi$ such that $L(s,\chi) = 0. $

**Question 1:** In the case that $L(s,\chi) = 0$, is it possible to say what the first non zero Taylor coefficient is?

**Question 2:** Can we decompose (even if it is only conjecturally) $h(K),R(K),w(K)$ into factors corresponding to each Dirichlet character appearing in the decomposition of $\zeta_K$ . What about the order of vanishing of $L(0,\chi)$?

Comment: All of your questions have comprehensive and beautiful answers: providing them is exactly what the subject of Iwasawa theory was developed to do. You should perhaps read either Washington's *Cyclotomic Fields* or Coates and Sujatha's *Cyclotomic Fields and Zeta Values*.

Comment: I am a little familiar with Washington's book, could you suggest which chapters or theorems I should look at?

Answer (score 9):

All of your questions have comprehensive and beautiful answers: providing them is exactly what the subject of Iwasawa theory was developed to do. You should perhaps read either Washington's *Cyclotomic Fields* or Coates and Sujatha's *Cyclotomic Fields and Zeta Values*.

The order of vanishing of $L(s, \chi)$ at $s = 0$, and its leading term there, is described quite precisely by the results of Chapter 4 of Washington, particularly Corollary 4.4 and Theorem 4.9. (These are stated in terms of values at s = 1, but the functional equation given just after Theorem 4.5 relates $L(s, \chi) $and $L(1-s, \bar\chi)$.) From these results it follows that:

- if $\chi(-1) = -1$, or $\chi$ is trivial, then $L(\chi, 0)$ is a non-zero algebraic number.
- if $\chi(-1) = +1$ and $\chi$ is non-trivial, then $L(\chi, 0) = 0$ and $L'(\chi, 0)$ is a non-zero $\overline{\mathbf{Q}}$-linear combination of logarithms of algebraic numbers (more specifically, of cyclotomic units).

As for decomposing $h(K)$ etc into pieces corresponding to Dirichlet characters, you might want to look at Chapter 10 -- in particular Corollary 10.15 and the remark following it, which explain such a decomposition for the p-part of the class group when $K = \mathbf{Q}(\zeta_p)$.